# Does TensorFlow differentiate through builtin optimization?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm implementing an [Unrolled GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02163) and I'm using calls to `optimizer.minimize` to update my discriminator weights for 5 or so steps before updating my generator.

My question is whether the call to update my generator will implicitly backprop through the 5 updates to the discriminator values?

Perhaps the important question to ask is whether Variable objects retain the graphs computing their assignments throughout time?

Unfortunately, when I run:

```
a = tf.Variable(0.1)
b = tf.Variable(0.0)

op = tf.no_op()
for _ in range(5):
  with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
    op = b.assign_add(a)

g = tf.gradients(b, a)
```

g is None, suggesting that Variables ignore the graph leading to their assignments. I would hope that the gradient would be 0.5, or at the very least it would keep the latest assignment's graph and evaluate to 0.1...

Answer (score 0):

Here a, b are independent variables, so gradients will be None; assignment only changes the values, doesn't create dependency.

```
a = tf.Variable(0.1)
b = tf.Variable(0.0)

op = tf.no_op()
for _ in range(5):
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
        op = b.assign_add(a)

# If you create a op that depends on a, gradients won't be None
b1 = a*b
g = tf.gradients(b1, a)
```

> My question is whether the call to update my generator will implicitly backprop through the 5 updates to the discriminator values?

So the answer of the question is yes, if you set up the dependencies.

Comment: Of course, a*b would resolve to the correct gradient, but not for the right reason. This answer doesn't provide me with any new information.